# Angular: animation display card on top of another card

Tags: css, angular, angular7, angular-animations, angular-material-6

Im using angular animation builder for creating an animation. I have a grid list with a list of cards. When i click on a button ,i want another div to come on top of the initial card (float in from the left to cover the first card
) .As of now,the div comes in with the animation ,but is showing up on side of the initial card.I have made a stackblitz example to show the current progress.Here is my stackblitz:

https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ty4rfh

Also pasting the code here:

```
import { Component,OnInit,ElementRef } from '@angular/core';
import { trigger, state, style, transition, animate, AnimationBuilder, AnimationPlayer } from '@angular/animations';

export class Asset
{
  constructor(public name:string,public description:string){};
}

@Component({
  selector: 'my-app',
  templateUrl: './app.component.html',
  styleUrls: [ './app.component.css' ]
})
export class AppComponent  {
  name = 'Angular';
  assets:Asset[]=[];
  cards=[];
  private player: AnimationPlayer;

  constructor(private animationBuilder:AnimationBuilder,
  private elRef:ElementRef
  ){}

  ngOnInit(){
    this.setAssets();
    this.setswitch();
  }

  setAssets(){
    this.assets.push(new Asset("Asset1","Latest1"));
    this.assets.push(new Asset("Asset2","Latest2"));
    this.assets.push(new Asset("Asset3","Latest3"));
    this.assets.push(new Asset("Asset4","Latest4"));
    this.assets.push(new Asset("Asset5","Latest5"));
    this.assets.push(new Asset("Asset6","Latest6"));
    this.assets.push(new Asset("Asset7","Latest7"));
    this.assets.push(new Asset("Asset8","Latest8"));
    this.assets.push(new Asset("Asset9","Latest9"));

    for(var i=0; i<this.assets.length;i++){
    console.log(this.assets[i].name);
    }
  }

    setswitch() {
    for (let i = 0; i < this.assets.length; i++) {
      let cardshow = {
        id: i.toString(),
        isShow : false
      };
      this.cards.push(cardshow);

    }
      console.log(this.cards);
  }

  animate(i){
    this.cards[i].isShow=true;
    let animationFactory;
      animationFactory = this.animationBuilder
        .build([
          style({ width: '0' }),
          animate(200, style({ width: 200 }))
        ]);  
  let elem:Element = document.getElementById("div"+(i));
  console.log("Elament",elem);
  console.log("INDEX",i);
  this.player = animationFactory.create(elem);
  this.player.play();

  }
}
```

html:

```
<div>
    <mat-grid-list cols="3" rowHeight="3:1">
        <mat-grid-tile *ngFor="let asset of assets; index as i">
    <div class="border">
      <p>{{asset.name}} </p>
            <p>{{asset.description}} </p>
            <button (click)="animate(i)">click</button>
         </div>

          <div [ngClass]="!cards[i].isShow?'hide':''" id="{{'div'+i}}" class="border" >

            <p>{{asset.description}} </p>
            <button>click</button>
         </div>

  </mat-grid-tile>
</mat-grid-list>
</div>
```

css:

```
     p {
  font-family: Lato;
}

.border{
  border:1px solid black;
  padding-left: 20px;;
  padding-right:20px;
}

.hide{
  display:none;
}
```

**EDIT**: I need the other card to be completely hidden under the incoming card.Also after clicking on the button inside the incoming card, the animation should be undone(The card should retract back). Also what I'm doing now is increasing the width. What i expect is that the new card should come in from the left sort of like as we see in a drawer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is my final solution:

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { LearningContentService } from '../../../service/learningcontent.service';
import { ActivatedRoute } from '@angular/router'

import { trigger, style, transition, animate, keyframes, query, stagger } from '@angular/animations';

export class Asset {
  name: string;
  description: string;
  cardtoggle:boolean=false;
  constructor(rawObj: any) {
    this.name = rawObj.name;
    this.description = rawObj.description;
    this.cardtoggle = rawObj.cardtoggle;

  }
}

@Component({
  selector: 'app-catalogue',
  templateUrl: './catalogue.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./catalogue.component.scss'],
  animations: [
    trigger('listAnimation', [
      transition('* => *', [

        query(':enter', style({ opacity: 0 }), { optional: true }),

        query(':enter', stagger('50ms', [
          animate('1s ease-in', keyframes([
            style({ opacity: 0, transform: 'translateY(-75%)', offset: 0 }),
            style({ opacity: .5, transform: 'translateY(35px)', offset: 0.3 }),
            style({ opacity: 1, transform: 'translateY(0)', offset: 1.0 }),
          ]))]), { optional: true })
      ])
    ],
    ),
  ]
})
export class CatalogueComponent implements OnInit {
  assets: Array<Asset> = [];

  constructor(private route: ActivatedRoute,
    private learningService: LearningContentService,
  ) {

  }

  ngOnInit() {
    this.loadAssets();

  }


  loadAssets() {
    this.learningService.assets().subscribe((res: any) => {
      const datas: Array<any> = res;
      datas.forEach(asset => this.assets.push(new Asset(asset)));
      console.log(this.assets);
    });
  }

  animate(asset) {
    asset.cardtoggle = true;
  }
  close(asset) {
    asset.cardtoggle = false;
  }
}
```

html:

```
<div fxLayout="column">
  <div fxLayout="row">
    <p class="page-heading" fxFlex="80%">Catalogue</p>
    <div class="page-content-filter" fxLayoutAlign="end">
      <button mat-button class="search-btn"><i class="material-icons"> search </i></button>
      <input class="form-filter" matInput placeholder="Search...">
    </div>
  </div>
  <mat-grid-list gutterSize="20px" cols="3" rowHeight="3:1" [@listAnimation]="assets.length">
    <mat-grid-tile *ngFor="let asset of assets">
      <div class="full-width white">
        <div class="padding20px" fxLayout="column" fxLayoutGap="15px">
          <div fxLayout="row" fxLayoutGap="15px">
            <img fxFlex="10" style="width:50px;height:50px;" src="../../../../assets/images/images.jpeg" mat-card-image>
            <b fxFlex="100">{{asset.name}}</b>
            <mat-icon fxLayoutAlign="end end" class="small-icon pointer" (click)="animate(asset)">spa</mat-icon>
          </div>
          <div fxLayout="row" fxLayoutGap="10px">
            <mat-icon class="small-icon">person</mat-icon>
            <p class="small-heading"> Mohit Harshan</p>
            <mat-divider vertical="true"></mat-divider>
            <mat-icon class="small-icon">play_arrow</mat-icon>
            <p class="small-heading">Video</p>
            <mat-divider vertical="true"></mat-divider>
            <mat-icon class="small-icon">face</mat-icon>
            <p class="small-heading">5 points</p>
          </div>
          <mat-progress-bar class="progress" mode="determinate" value="40"></mat-progress-bar>
        </div>
      </div>

      <div class="pull-right" [ngClass]="{'show': asset.cardtoggle }" class="card2">
        <div class="padding20px" fxLayout="column" fxLayoutGap="15px">
          <div fxLayout="row" fxLayoutGap="15px">
            <b fxFlex="100" class="small-heading">{{asset.name}}</b>
            <mat-icon fxLayoutAlign="end end" class="small-icon pointer" (click)="close(asset)">clear</mat-icon>
          </div>
          <div fxLayout="row" fxLayoutGap="10px">
           <p class="small">{{asset.description}}</p>
          </div>
          <div fxLayout="row" fxLayoutGap="10px" fxFLex="100" fxLayoutAlign="end end">
            <button fxFLex="100" mat-button class="green-button" >View Details</button>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </mat-grid-tile>
  </mat-grid-list>
</div>
```

css:

```
.card2{ 
    position:absolute; 
    z-index: 20; 
    background: white; 
    padding-left: 0px; 
    padding-right:0px; 
    width:100%; 
    height:100%;
    margin-left: 100%;
    transition: margin-left .5s ease-in-out;
} 

.show { 
    margin-left: 0%;
} 

.green-button{
  border:1px solid lightgreen;
  border-radius: 10%;
  font-size: 10px;
  color:green;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

check this [stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-lppxaa?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.css)

**app.component.css** to be:

```
p {
  font-family: Lato;
}

.border{
  border:1px solid black;
  padding-left: 20px;;
  padding-right:20px;
  background: #ffe6ea;
}

.hide{
  display:none;
}

.borderPopUp{
  padding-left: 20px;;
  padding-right:20px;
  position:absolute;
  background:#d3d3d3d4;
  animation: openLikeDrawer 800ms ease-in-out;
  width:50%;
  left:20%;
}

@keyframes openLikeDrawer{
  from {left:0px; }
  to { left: 20%; }
}
```

**app.component.html** to be :

```
<div>
    <mat-grid-list cols="3" rowHeight="3:1">
        <mat-grid-tile *ngFor="let asset of assets; index as i">
            <div class="border">
                <p>{{asset.name}} </p>
                <p>{{asset.description}} </p>
                <button (click)="asset.isShow = true">click</button> 

      </div>

      <div *ngIf="asset.isShow" class="borderPopUp" >
        <p>{{asset.description}} </p>
        <button (click)='asset.isShow = false'>click</button>
      </div>

    </mat-grid-tile>
  </mat-grid-list>
</div>
```

Comment: Can you make it a bit more like what i need. I need the other card to be completely hidden under the incoming card.Also after clicking on the button inside the incoming card, the animation should be undoed(The card should retract back)..Also what im doing now is increasing the width.What i expect is that the new card should come in from the left sort of like as we see in a drawer

Comment: let me share that Mohit

Comment: do you want to use angular animate... how about doing this without that ? but pure angular ?

Comment: can you please check my updated stackblitz and tell me ehat you make of it .It has some more logical errors to be corrected

Comment: observations (1) too much code for simple stuff... (2) if i open and then close cell2... after that if I open any cell, cell2 becomes visible again... this is something which screws up the intended logic... consider using renderer instead of elementRef for DOM manipulation (but ultimately avoid both if you can with different application design)

Comment: Please check my latest code.Can you make it come from the side instead of expanding from the middle?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/191359/discussion-between-akber-iqbal-and-mohit-harshan).